DOS int 21h / AH=09h is outputting the contents of my NASM source file to the console, not the desired string
I'm working in NASM, for DOSBox, in 16-bit real mode. At 15th line, I trying to output field_separator string, but get my .asm file content. I suspect that I'm using the wrong register, or that I've occupied a register that I shouldn't have. When I trying to print line in empty file, it works great, but here is troubles
org 100h

mov bx, field

mov ah, 02h
call print_field

mov ah, 4CH
int 21h

print_field:

    movzx di, byte [currentFieldIndex]
    mov bx, 3
    mov dx, field_separator ; HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    print_field_line_loop:
        mov ah, 02h
        mov cx, 3
        print_field_char_loop:
            call start_compare
            mov dl, "|$"
            int 21h
            
            inc di
            loop print_field_char_loop
        dec bx
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        cmp byte [bx], 0
        jne print_field_line_loop
    ret

start_compare:
    cmp byte [bx+di], 0
    je print_cell
    call compare_x
    ret

compare_x:
    cmp byte [bx+di], 1
    je print_x
    call print_o
    ret

print_cell:
    mov dl, " $"
    int 21h
    ret

print_x:
    mov dl, "X$"
    int 21h
    ret

print_o:
    mov dl, "O$"
    int 21h
    ret

field: db 0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
currentTurn: db 0
field_separator: db 13,10,"-+-+-$", 0
currentFieldIndex: db 0

output
Need to print CRLF + "-+-+-".

If you place mov ah, 08h, int 21h before print_field_line_loop you will see that ah=09h works alright.

Writing two ASCII text immediates to the dl register should warn about an overflow. Don't do that. (Likely not related to your question.)

bx+di in start_compare doesn't address field because you overwrote bx in mov bx, 3. Even so, cmp byte [bx], 0 doesn't seem like it would work as intended for your loop end condition.

Crucial: Your int 21h after the loop instruction will display garbage because you corrupted dx since mov dx, field_separator. Remember that dl is the low byte of dx so changing dl will also change dx.

After loop print_field_char_loop, dx should point to correct string address. dl is changed in print_cell, print_x, print_o.

@Nassau mov ah, 08h does not work. But thanks for point me to changing of dl in my print label - after moving field_separator to dl after dec bx line my code start working
@ecm thank you for warning me about bx and dl-dx!!!!!

@kingley mov ah,08h waits for a user to press a key. Idea was to stop the program to show that field_separator is correctly printed on the screen and problem lies somewhere in the rest part of the code.
